# Как сделать Unit Test этого статичного метода?

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

Почему-то вызывает проблемы тестирование этого метода `GetById`. Надеюсь на вашу помощь. (C#)

```
public class ProductTypes: Archetypes<ProductType>
{
    public static ProductTypes Instance { get; } = new ProductTypes();

    public static ProductType GetById(string uniqueId)
    {
        return Instance.Find(x=> x.IsThisUniqueId(uniqueId));
    }

    public static ProductTypes GetInherited(string uniqueId)
    {
        var t = new ProductTypes();
        var l = Instance.FindAll(x => x.TypeId == uniqueId);
        t.AddRange(l);
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow! Вы, возможно, считаете людей, отвечающих здесь на вопросы, волшебниками. Однако, наше волшебство не настолько сильно, чтобы угадать, что Вы имеете в виду под словом "проблемы".

Comment: Не знаю как делать..

Comment: Хорошо, зайдем с другой стороны. Чем Вас не устраивает показанный код?

Comment: Всем устраивает) нужно сделать его модульное тестирование.

Comment: В чем проблема? если ошибка во время выполнения теста, то какая? Причину скорее всего нужно искать в `Instance.Find(...)`. `Archetypes<T>` покрыт тестами полностью? они проходят?